# What am I gonna do with that AppID?

Tags: iphone

I had to make a new AppID in order to get my provisioning profiles working. But I completely forgot: If I make an AppID with no wildcard, I can only run those apps on my test device that have this AppID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you are not specifying any wild card then with generated provision profile with that id can only run those apps on your test device that have same AppID.

Jim.